# Moq Expression<Func<>>

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq

Im trying to mock `Expression<Func<>>` exactly how it should work in class that im testing.

My original declaration of this method looks like this:

```
var entity = await _repository.GetByIdAsync(input.Id1, x => x.Id2 == "Some String");
```

Now i want to mock that method using `Moq`:

```
// Arrange
entity.Id2 = "Some id";

// Act
_rRepositoryMock.Setup(x =>
    x.GetByIdAsync(
        It.Is<string>(y => y == input.Id1),
        It.Is<Expression<Func<MyEntity, object>>>(z => z.Id2 == "Some id")))
.ReturnsAsync(entity);
```

From `Moq` code i get this error, that `Expression<Func<>>` does not contein definition of `Id2`.

How to Mock in `Moq` `Expression<Func<>>` to work exatly as i want to in original implementation?

**EDIT**

When i type something like:

```
It.Is<Expression<Func<MyEntity, object>>>(z => z = p => p.Id2 == "Some string")))
```

I get this error:

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error   CS1662  Cannot convert lambda expression to intended delegate type because some of the return types in the block are not implicitly convertible to the delegate return type
>
> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error   CS0029  Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Linq.Expressions.Expression>' to 'bool'

**EDIT2**

Signature of the method to mock:

```
Task<MyEntity> GetByIdAsync(string id, params Expression<Func<MyEntity, object>>[] @params);
```

Comment: Could you show us the signature of `GetByIdAsync`?

Comment: @Caramiriel look at my Edit1 and Edit2

Comment: You're almost there on your initial try. :) Note that the second parameter is an array (`[]`), but isn't in your mock. Could you try to add that?

Comment: I Found solution, check my answer

Answer (score 0):

I found solution. You dont need to mock `Expression<Func>>`, you can simply pass func to `Moq` like this:

```
_repositoryMock.Setup(x =>
    x.GetByIdAsync(
        It.Is<string>(y => y == input.Id1),
        z => z.Id2 == "Some id"))
.ReturnsAsync(entity);
```